# Is it possible to update rustup once and share the downloads with other systems?

Tags: rust, rustup

I'd like to save bandwidth by invoking `rustup update` and updating the installed toolchains, then sharing the updated toolchains to another system without having to download the toolchains again. Is this possible?

Looking at the .rustup directory, it seems copying the toolchains directory might work but I'm afraid of causing a mismatch between rustup's metadata on what it has installed and what's actually installed, or other such problems. Unless someone says it's OK to do this, I don't think this is an option.